# Convert MagickImage to bitmap

Tags: c#, magicknet

I thought it would be easier, but I can't find a way to do it. How can I convert a MagickImage to System.Drawing.Image (eg a Bitmap)

```
    public System.Drawing.Image CreateThumbnailIcon(string sourceImagePath, int iconSize )
    {
        MagickImage image = new MagickImage(sourceImagePath);
        MagickGeometry geometry = new MagickGeometry(iconSize, iconSize);
        image.Resize(geometry);
        return image.??????;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot confirm this works, I am doing this from memory, but give it  a try:

```
MagickImage image = new MagickImage(sourceImagePath);
MagickGeometry geometry = new MagickGeometry(iconSize, iconSize);
image.Resize(geometry);

using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  // Write the image to the memorystream
  image.Write(memStream);
  
  return new System.Drawing.Bitmap(memStream);
}
```

Comment: It works like charm, too! And without the need to add Magick.NET.SystemDrawing!

Comment: I had to add a line just before the Write: image.Format = MagickFormat.Bmp; This is probably because I create my image from scratch and not from an existing source. May help some people.

Answer (score 3):

For net framework you can use `ToBitmap` extension [method](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/3b22c0436037cc3fdc11ff835675c7e55e9a6e21/src/Magick.NET.SystemDrawing/IMagickImageExtentions.cs#L48)

For net core / net5+ - there is no way out of the box and author of Magick.NET just saying "do not use `System.Drawing` in the new code".

But, if you really need this, you can use [extension methods](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/issues/543#issuecomment-569049907) from corresponding GitHub issue

```
    public enum BitmapDensity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Ignore the density of the image when creating the bitmap.
        /// </summary>
        Ignore,

        /// <summary>
        /// Use the density of the image when creating the bitmap.
        /// </summary>
        Use,
    }

    public static class MagickImageExtensions
    {
        [SuppressMessage("Reliability", "CA2000:Dispose objects before losing scope", Justification = "False positive.")]
        public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this MagickImage imageMagick, BitmapDensity bitmapDensity)
        {
            string mapping = "BGR";
            var format = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;

            var image = imageMagick;

            try
            {
                if( image.ColorSpace != ColorSpace.sRGB )
                {
                    image = (MagickImage)imageMagick.Clone();
                    image.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.sRGB;
                }

                if( image.HasAlpha )
                {
                    mapping = "BGRA";
                    format = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                }

                using( IPixelCollection pixels = image.GetPixelsUnsafe() )
                {
                    var bitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, format);
                    var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, format);
                    var destination = data.Scan0;
                    for( int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++ )
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = pixels.ToByteArray(0, y, image.Width, 1, mapping);
                        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, destination, bytes.Length);

                        destination = new IntPtr(destination.ToInt64() + data.Stride);
                    }

                    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

                    SetBitmapDensity(imageMagick, bitmap, bitmapDensity);
                    return bitmap;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if( ! ReferenceEquals(image, imageMagick) )
                    image.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this MagickImage imageMagick) => ToBitmap(imageMagick, BitmapDensity.Ignore);

        public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this MagickImage imageMagick, ImageFormat imageFormat) => ToBitmap(imageMagick, imageFormat, BitmapDensity.Ignore);

        public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this MagickImage imageMagick, ImageFormat imageFormat, BitmapDensity bitmapDensity)
        {
            imageMagick.Format = InternalMagickFormatInfo.GetFormat(imageFormat);

            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            imageMagick.Write(memStream);
            memStream.Position = 0;

            /* Do not dispose the memStream, the bitmap owns it. */
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(memStream);

            SetBitmapDensity(imageMagick, bitmap, bitmapDensity);

            return bitmap;
        }

        public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this MagickImage imageMagick)
        {
            return ToBitmapSource(imageMagick, BitmapDensity.Ignore);
        }

        [SuppressMessage("Reliability", "CA2000:Dispose objects before losing scope", Justification = "False positive.")]
        public static System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this MagickImage imageMagick, BitmapDensity bitmapDensity)
        {
            IMagickImage image = imageMagick;

            var mapping = "RGB";
            var format = MediaPixelFormats.Rgb24;

            try
            {
                if (imageMagick.ColorSpace == ColorSpace.CMYK && !image.HasAlpha)
                {
                    mapping = "CMYK";
                    format = MediaPixelFormats.Cmyk32;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (imageMagick.ColorSpace != ColorSpace.sRGB)
                    {
                        image = (MagickImage) imageMagick.Clone();
                        image.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.sRGB;
                    }

                    if (image.HasAlpha)
                    {
                        mapping = "BGRA";
                        format = MediaPixelFormats.Bgra32;
                    }
                }

                var step = format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
                var stride = imageMagick.Width * step;

                using (IPixelCollection pixels = image.GetPixelsUnsafe())
                {
                    var bytes = pixels.ToByteArray(mapping);
                    var dpi = GetDpi(imageMagick, bitmapDensity);
                    return BitmapSource.Create(imageMagick.Width, imageMagick.Height, dpi.X, dpi.Y, format, null, bytes, stride);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!ReferenceEquals(imageMagick, image))
                    image.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static void FromBitmap(this MagickImage imageMagick, Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                if (IsSupportedImageFormat(bitmap.RawFormat))
                    bitmap.Save(memStream, bitmap.RawFormat);
                else
                    bitmap.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

                memStream.Position = 0;
                imageMagick.Read(memStream);
            }
        }

        private static bool IsSupportedImageFormat(ImageFormat format)
        {
            return
                format.Guid.Equals(ImageFormat.Bmp.Guid) ||
                format.Guid.Equals(ImageFormat.Gif.Guid) ||
                format.Guid.Equals(ImageFormat.Icon.Guid) ||
                format.Guid.Equals(ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid) ||
                format.Guid.Equals(ImageFormat.Png.Guid) ||
                format.Guid.Equals(ImageFormat.Tiff.Guid);
        }

        private static void SetBitmapDensity(MagickImage imageMagick, Bitmap bitmap, BitmapDensity bitmapDensity)
        {
            if (bitmapDensity == BitmapDensity.Use)
            {
                var dpi = GetDpi(imageMagick, bitmapDensity);
                bitmap.SetResolution((float)dpi.X, (float)dpi.Y);
            }
        }

        private static Density GetDpi(MagickImage imageMagick, BitmapDensity bitmapDensity)
        {
            if (bitmapDensity == BitmapDensity.Ignore || (imageMagick.Density.Units == DensityUnit.Undefined && imageMagick.Density.X == 0 && imageMagick.Density.Y == 0))
                return new Density(96);

            return imageMagick.Density.ChangeUnits(DensityUnit.PixelsPerInch);
        }
    }

    public class InternalMagickFormatInfo
    {
        internal static MagickFormat GetFormat(ImageFormat format)
        {
            if (format == ImageFormat.Bmp || format == ImageFormat.MemoryBmp)
                return MagickFormat.Bmp;
            else if (format == ImageFormat.Gif)
                return MagickFormat.Gif;
            else if (format == ImageFormat.Icon)
                return MagickFormat.Icon;
            else if (format == ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                return MagickFormat.Jpeg;
            else if (format == ImageFormat.Png)
                return MagickFormat.Png;
            else if (format == ImageFormat.Tiff)
                return MagickFormat.Tiff;
            else
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported image format: " + format.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can see Magick.NET.SystemDrawing available through NuGet, with the method 'ToBitmap' and many others implemented